# Why appended list cannot be assign to a variable?

Tags: python, list, append

```
student = {
    'Tom': 'A1',
    'Amy': 'B2',
    'John': 'C3',
}

student_id = []
for i in student.values():
    print(i)
    student_id.append(i)
print(student_id)
```

The outcome for the above code is:

```
A
B
C
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

But when I assign the appended list to variable a, it yields a different outcome:

```
student = {
    'Tom': 'A',
    'Amy': 'B',
    'John': 'C',
}

student_id = []
for i in student.values():
    print(i)
    a = student_id.append(i)
print(a)
```

The outcome become：

```
A
B
C
None
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: append is a inplace operation thus does not hanve a return value

Comment: `.append` doesn't return any values, it just appends those data in that reference..

Comment: Not only is append an inplace operation, each iteration in the for loop creates a new instance of a.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Or is this just experimenting?